# App keeps fetching firebase data with button click [ReactJs] (CLOSED)

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component, rerender

I have an online restaurant app that fetches the menu items from firebase. It fetches everytime I add something to the cart, which makes the menu items disappear and then reappear for a second. It also scrolls back to the top of the page after every click. How do I prevent this reload? e.preventDefault() doesnt work. Is it due to the passing of data from the child to the parent? I'm not sure.

```
//imports

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const Menue = (props) => {

  
  const [cartLength, setCartLength] = useState(0);

  const [indischeGerichte, setIndischeGerichte] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    fire.firestore().collection("Indische Gerichte")
    .orderBy("id", "asc")
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      var ind = []
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        ind.push(doc.data())
      })
      setIndischeGerichte(ind)
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    });
  }, [])
  function addToCart(e, item) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var updatedCart = { ...props.cart };
    if (!updatedCart[item.title]) {
      updatedCart[item.title] = [1, item.price];
    } else {
      updatedCart[item.title][0]++;
    }
    setCartLength(cartLength + 1);
    props.setTheCart(updatedCart, cartLength);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Typography variant="h3" component="h2" gutterBottom>
        Speisekarte
      </Typography>
      <div id="ind">
        <Typography variant="h4">Indian Foods:</Typography>
        {indischeGerichte.map((indFood, idx) => {
          return (
            <div key={idx}>
              <Card className="foodCard">
                <Typography variant="h4">{indFood.title}</Typography>
                <Button
                  variant="contained"
                  color="secondary"
                  onClick={(e) => addToCart(e, indFood)}
                >
                  1x In den Einkaufswagen
                </Button>
              </Card>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Menue;
```

Comment: What happens when `props.setTheCart(updatedCart, cartLength);` is called? Also, how is the `setTheCart` function prop created?

Comment: It sends the cart to the parent component, which then saves it in the state there. That way I can pass data from the cart to the menu through the parent component.

Comment: Does `indFood` have an id that you can use as a `key` instead of the index of the loop? Also, when you do `props.setTheCart(updatedCart, cartLength);` is it supposed to happen "after" the state update? If yes, I don't think it works like that, you need to put `cartLength + 1` here as well

Comment: Yes, the cartLength is increased by one before the state in the parent component is changed.

Comment: Ok, I found a solution. Instead of retrieving the data in the menu component (page), it imports in the parent component and passes it as a prop. Works just fine now.